# Django Send emails to all users in the database table

Tags: python, django, email

I have started django building my first app tutorials, i have to send email to all my users store in the database table on some special Ocations. i have searched on google and found many apis but found it very hard to configure with my app.

here is my model.py

```
class Users(models.Model):
    UserID = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='User ID',max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    UserName = models.CharField(verbose_name='User Name',max_length=254,null=True,blank=True)
    Email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email',max_length=254,null=True,blank=True)
    Phone = models.CharField(verbose_name='Phone Number',max_length=254,null=True,blank=True)
```

i want to have a function here which should get all users one-by-one and send email also tells the status weather the email has been sent or not.

Answer (score 6):

battery's answer is ok, but i would do this way:

```
recievers = []
for user in Users.objects.all():
    recievers.append(user.email)

send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recievers)
```

this way, you will open only once connection to mail server rather than opening for each email.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email is very simple. 
For your `Users` model this would be:

```
for user in Users.objects.all():
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email,
        user.Email)
```

Checkout [Django's Documentation on send emails](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/) for more details.

Would be useful if you mention what problem you are facing if you've tried this.

Also note, `IntegerField` does not have a `max_length` argument.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It does answer the question. It mentions how emails can be sent in django, accompanied by a reference link. In addition it does encourage the OP to provide additional information.

Comment: @Werner I agree, I'll add a more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score -1):

for user in Users.objects.all():
send_mail(subject, message, from_email,
user.Email)

This is the best solutions and it works well