# accessing Django user email list

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a page for the admin of a website to access to write a message to there email list for registered users on a website.

My idea was to create a new form 2 fields:
field 1: Subject
field 2: message

then send a email to all registered users. The part I can't really find much information is how to pass the email list to recipient_list in send_mail(). I am not sure how to access the email list data.

I'm using Django/python
Any articles on doing this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Don't pass it to the recepients! It means that everybody can see the other people's email address! Usually one uses a bcc to prevent *leaking* email addresses.

Comment: ok thanks I'll find more information on that.

Comment: If the email address of each user is provided/set when the user is created and you use the default ```User``` model (```from django.contrib.auth.models import User```) then you can access the email address of a user using ```user.email```.

Comment: @AaronScheib I am using the default user model. How do I access all users emails? to create a email list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the Django default `User` model have a look at this question/answer [Django Send emails to all users in the database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27664175/django-send-emails-to-all-users-in-the-database-table), I think this should get it.